# No module named 'nornir_utils'

Tags: python-3.x, netmiko

i am trying to work with nornir but i get this

whene i try this :

`from nornir.plugins.functions.text import print_result`

i get this:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nornir.plugins.functions.text'
```

i've also tried this:

```
from nornir_utils.plugins.functions import print_result
```

the probleme is still there:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nornir.plugins.functions.text'
```

can anyone help me solve this ?

Comment: The problem is solved?

Comment: @CarloZanocco yes thanks , it's been while since i played with nornir .. they changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in the [`nornir`](https://nornir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module docs there is no [`print_result`](https://nornir.tech/nornir_utils/html/tutorials/function_print_title.html?highlight=print_result#functions:-print_result) function, but it is present in the [`nornir_utils`](https://nornir.tech/nornir_utils/html/index.html) module.

The plugins present in `nornir` are four, look [here](https://nornir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/index.html#registering-plugins)

You can install the `nornir_utils` module with `pip install nornir_utils` and the `nornir` module as `pip install nornir`.

The corrent import to do is `from nornir_utils.plugins.functions import print_result`.

Make sure to use the right pip to install the packages, sometimes I install in the wrong env having multiple python installation.